# Accessing experimentId and experimentVariant with bigquery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I want to access the experimentId und experimentVariant along with additional engagement data from google analytics.

When trying

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitNumber,
  totals.pageviews,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  hits.experiment.experimentId,
  hits.experiment.experimentVariant

FROM  `xy_20170809`, UNNEST(hits) as hits

WHERE
   hits.type = “PAGE”

ORDER BY
   fullVisitorId ASC, visitNumber ASC
```

the following error occurs

> Cannot access field experimentId on a value with type
>   ARRAY< STRUCT< experimentId STRING, experimentVariant STRING>> at

It seems like unnesting the hits.experiment ARRAY does not work as expected, unnesting the hits.page ARRAY is working properly.
The only difference I found is that hits.experiment is an repeated array while hits.page is nullable.

Any ideas how to access the experimentId and experimentVariant?

Answer (score 3):

As a given `fullvisitorID` can potentially be part of different tests/variation, the field `experiment` is repeated just like the `hits` field.

This means you'll have to `unnest` it as well:

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitNumber,
  totals.pageviews,
  hits.page.pagePath,
  e.experimentId,
  e.experimentVariant
FROM  `xy_20170809`,
UNNEST(hits) as hits,
UNNEST(hits.experiment) AS e
WHERE
   hits.type = “PAGE”
ORDER BY
   fullVisitorId ASC, visitNumber ASC
```

I usually tend to avoid unnestings on the hits field as much as possible (so to have good performance and nested results for the most part). One way you could do this is by running something like:

```
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid fv,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT experimentID, experimentVariant FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(experiment))
FROM `xy_20170809`
LIMIT 1000
```

But you have to analyze if it's a good approach for you. Nevertheless it's another technique for you to use in BigQuery if necessary.

[EDIT]:

Here's a query for selecting only users who had some variation:

```
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid fv,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT experimentID, experimentVariant FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(experiment))
FROM `xy_20170809`
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT experimentID, experimentVariant FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(experiment))) > 0
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thanks alot. The query is running without an error now. Unfortunatelly when adding the "unnest(hits.experiment) as e" line, big query is returning zero records. 

Leaving the e.experimenId, e.experimentVariant select items and "unnest(hits.experiment) as e" out, bigquery is returning the data.

Do you have any idea on that issue?

Comment: This is probably happening because of the clause `where hits.type = 'PAGE'`. When an experiment happens, G.A saves it as an `EVENT` type and not `PAGE`. Maybe removing it will bring the data as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
Just gave it a try and it is still returning zero records.

Seems like the second UNNEST statements somehow cleans the output!?

Comment: I wonder what happens if you run the second query I posted, the one that brings the result as ARRAY. Does all fullvisitorIDs appear with empty values for experiments? This being the case then probably all your experiment values are empty so that's why the unnest would return zero results.

Comment: It returns a table with the columns f0_.experimentID and f0_.experimentVariant being grayed out. I took a screenshot: [bigquery result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wadk8bvz9n3lb2f/bigquery.jpg?dl=0)
Does that mean it is empty or an unsupported data type (for 
 visualisation)? In the JSON tab, it is an empty array: "f0_": [] ([biquery json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzwjw180yp0qzzc/bigquery_json.jpg?dl=0) )

Comment: I edited my answer. If you run the query with the where clause having the `array_length` and it returns zero results, that would mean your table does not have values for the experiments.

Comment: Hi again. Just retested the query with `array_length` and it returned zero.

Mhm..do you have any idea why those variables are empty although we were running several Google Analytics content Tests during the test period?

Comment: hmm don't know. Some debugging seems to be required there. Make sure to use the [google analytics debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) and confirm if the events are indeed being sent as expected.

Comment: same here, the query returns no results