# experimentId NULL - bigquery query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I wrote this BigQuery query for having experimentId and Variant results but everything is NULL (except clientId).

I just precise that this query works fine usually for any hits but the fields for experiment are NULL.

```
SELECT
  clientId,
  e.experimentId,
  e.experimentVariant
FROM `ga_sessions` visit,
UNNEST(visit.hits) as hits
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits.experiment) AS e
```

Is it normal ? Because in Google Analytics API for Experiment, they are well tracked but nothing appears in BigQuery ... is there something going wrong backend ? Something to activate ?

Thanks you by advance

Comment: When I try this query in the Google Analytics 360 public dataset it fails, giving zero results. I believe this may be a bug in the BigQuery export, as suggested in the comments of this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978680/accessing-experimentid-and-experimentvariant-with-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

A good point to start is checking the BigQuery logs; if there are errors during the loading (from GA to BQ) you need to check the error message to figure out whats is happening, and solve it.

But if there are not errors in BigQuery, it means (for me) that GA is not sending Experiment values, I would say that something else needs to be activated; however, there is a warning notice in GA documentation that could be impacting you:

> Beginning August 7, 2019, you won't be able to create or start
>   [Content Experiments (CX)](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9366791#resource).

and it is recommended:

> If you have any experiments in progress, consider migrating them to
>   [Google Optimize](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/optimize/?utm_source%3Dproduct%26utm_medium%3Demail%26utm_campaign%3D2019-q2-gbl-all-optimize%26utm_content%3Dcontent-experiments-is-being-replaced-with-optimize).

So, the recomendation is to use Google Optimize instead Experiments.

Hope it helps.